# Who/what is eating my mint?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, insects, mint

Who/what is eating my mint? What should I do about it? Can I do something organic? I had destroyed my mint a year ago by spraying a pesticide, so I don't want to go that route.

I live in Jaipur, India. The current temperature is 22-35 degree C (70-75 F).

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like your culprit is smallish. Candidates would be

- caterpillars
  Check for their droppings - greenish or blackish "pearls" - or the animals themselves hiding either under the leaves or along the stems. Simply pick them off, no chemicals needed.
- slugs or snails
  tend to leave slimy traces - search and remove like caterpillars.
- bugs
  rather unlikely, but a close inspection should clarify this soon. Proceed as above.

Comment: What should i do now ? Any organic pesticide ?

Comment: Unless you have *very many pots*, use tweezers or your hands and *simply pluck them off*. You just have to *find* them, but that probably needs just some close inspection, if necessary, check the plants at night.

Comment: If it's bugs, a strong fan, or vacuum cleaner set to reverse can blow most of them off.

Comment: "Check the plant at night" ...what difference should be there?

Comment: @Saurabh Some are nocturnal - they hide during the day and come out to eat at night.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I checked today and saw there were many very small bugs. Tweezers would not work on those. I used water with pressure on them and most of them are gone, Also changed the pot place (with more sun now), Lets see if this helps.